# I can't get the VirtualGuests location name using softlayer Rest API

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I can't get the location longName (Paris, Amsterdam, ...) using this URL
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectMask=mask[id,hostname,domain,primaryIpAddress,primaryBackendIpAddress,location[id,name,longName]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the control portal use the relational property **datacenter** instead of location to retrieve the information you need, try this request:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectMask=mask[id,hostname,domain,primaryIpAddress,primaryBackendIpAddress,datacenter[id,name,longName]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a property for the device Type, please?

Comment: Yes, this is called **typeId**, it gives the type of guest categorized as PUBLIC, DEDICATED or PRIVATE. You may try this by adding this local property to your object mask, for example **Dedicated** VirtualGuests will display a statusId = 2.